# Hide elements of html in slider using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Iam using this slider http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/background-slideshow/ for fully background slider. I added some image in the class main:-

```
   <style>
       .mobile {
           visibility:hidden;
       }
       @media(max-width:480px) {
           .desktop {
               visibility:hidden.
           }
           .mobile {
               visibility:visible;
           }
      }
</style>
<ul id="cbp-bislideshow" class="cbp-bislideshow">
                <li class="desktop"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="image01"/></li>
                <li class="desktop"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="image02"/></li>
                <li class="mobile"><img src="images/mobile/1.jpg" alt="image03"/></li>
                <li class="mobile"><img src="images/mobile/2.jpg" alt="image04"/></li>
</ul>
```

What i want to show image having class desktop and to hide image of class mobile and also to hide  class desktop  and show class mobile if browser having max-width of 480px. But after showing image of class desktop it shows white screen which i don't want. 
Please help.

Comment: Have you already tried to use `display:none;` instead of `visibility:hidden;`?

Comment: Use `display` instead of `visibility` ... visibility reserves the space for the element

Comment: @matthias_h i tried using display but it still showing me white screen after displaying class desktop images.

Comment: @jason: can you share the link to your website?

Comment: Possibly `display:none !important;` will work, just looked at the code of your slider and there all images are loaded and displayed using jquery.show(). Using `!important` could fix it.

Comment: @FahadHasan i use the code of this link:- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/background-slideshow/

Comment: @matthias_h nope it still showing the same problem. Have u tried the code ?

Comment: Have just tried on the example page and it won't work by just using css because of the js. The js counts all images and navigates to all of them. You could adjust the js to ignore images with class mobile if you're on mobile etc, if not, the next image will be "displayed"; in case this image has display:none you'll get this white screen for this image.

Comment: @matthias_h thanks man for trying code. Yup i feel exactly the same and i think m gonna do it using js to adjust for 480px.

Comment: What you could try though it may sound weird: add 2 sliders, one for desktop slideshow, one for mobile only, and init only the appropriate one at `var $slideshow = $( '#cbp-bislideshow' )`, then you maybe save the time to adjust the js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63370/discussion-between-jason-and-matthias-h).

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none` and `display: block` instead of `visibility: hidden` and `visibility: visible` respectively, like this:

```
<style>
       .mobile{
          display: none !important;;
       }
       @media (max-width:480px) {
       .desktop{
            display: none !important;;
        }
         .mobile{
          display: block !important;;
       }
   }
</style>
```